# How to check if a relationship has been established - Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsentitydescription

How would you check if a relationship has been established when adding data to core data? Currently I have a **TO MANY** relationship between two of my entities.

I am attempting to create a detail view but am struggling and i'm not sure if its due to a relationship not being established or if my issue is with passing the data over to the new view controller.

[image]

I am adding the the data to the core data entities using the following code. Does this look right when establishing a relationship between the two?

```
ExcerciseInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSManagedObject *routineEntity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routines"inManagedObjectContext:context];
NSManagedObject *routineEntityDetail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RoutinesDetails" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    
[[routineEntityDetail valueForKey:@"name"] addObject:routineEntity];
    
[routineEntity setValue: info.name  forKey:@"routinename"];
[routineEntityDetail setValue: info.details.muscle  forKey:@"image"];
   
NSError *error = nil;
```

Error Investigation:

I used one of the suggested methods but am still getting this fault when i tested the relationship in a `NSLog(@"ExTitle *** %@",Ex.routinedet);` with routinedet being the `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *routinedet;` in the core data generated NSObject relationship model:

```
Relationship 'routinedet' fault on managed object (0x749ea50) <Routines: 0x749ea50> (entity: Routines; id: 0x749c630 <x-coredata://C075DDEC-169D-46EC-A4B7-972A04FCED70/Routines/p1> ; data: {
    routinedet = "<relationship fault: 0x8184a20 'routinedet'>";
    routinename = "Leg Crunch";
```

I have also tested to make sure the segue is working and its is as;

```
self.title = Ex.routinename;
RoutinesDetails *info;
NSLog(@"Image *** %@",info.image);
```

which shows the title as the correct name but returns image string as null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the entities are defined as in [Core Data Detail View with relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553654/core-data-detail-view-with-relationship), the following code establishes a relationship between
the two objects:

```
[routineEntityDetail setValue:routineEntity forKey:@"routineinfo"];
```

It sets the relationship pointer from `routineEntityDetail` to `routineEntity`.

Since `routinedet` is the *inverse relationship* to `routineinfo`, `routineEntityDetail`
is automatically added to the `routinedet` relationship of `routineEntity`.

This does not make sense:

```
[[routineEntityDetail valueForKey:@"name"] addObject:routineEntity];
```

And this looks OK:

```
[routineEntity setValue: info.name  forKey:@"routinename"];
[routineEntityDetail setValue: info.details.muscle  forKey:@"image"];
```

Comment: Thanks again martin. So currently it wouldn't work? Is `[[routineEntityDetail valueForKey:@"name"] addObject:routineEntity];` not needed?

Comment: @user2221799: `name` is an attribute of `RoutineDetails`, not a relationship.

Comment: so on that basis i would simple change it to `rountineinfo` to match the relationship. Thanks

Comment: @user2221799: Yes, but `routineinfo` is a to-one relationship and `addObject` does not make sense here. The first code in my answer shows how to set the relationship.

Comment: brillant. you have been very helpful today martin

Comment: I actually just tested it out and got an error as viewable in the main question

Comment: @user2221799: A "fault" is not an error!!  Core Data will retrieve the values from the store file when needed.

Comment: @user2221799: There is nothing to "forgive". YOU decide when and which answer you accept!

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your datamodel I can't be sure, but I believe you would want something like this:

```
ExcerciseInfo *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
Routine  *routine = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Routine"inManagedObjectContext:context];
RoutineDetail  *routineDetail = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RoutineDetail" inManagedObjectContext:context];

routine.routineName = info.name;
routineDetail.image = info.details.muscle;

[routine addRoutineDetailsObject:routineDetail];
```

That assumes that a routine has many routineDetails, and that the relationship is named as it would be by generating the NSManagedObject subclass in XCode.  I also removed the plural name in the class names, as model classes are generally singular.

If my assumptions are off I apologize.

The datamodel I was coding for is here:
[image]

Comment: data model can be seen at the start of this post [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17553654/core-data-detail-view-with-relationship . Is that what you expected?

Comment: Yours doesn't follow the naming conventions that I am accustomed to, but that's not a bug deal.  I feel the bigger issue is the generation of the NSManagedObject subclasses.  In XCode you'll find that tool on the edit menu when you are looking at your datamodel.

Comment: But you don't reference the subclass in your code.  I meant generation of the .h and .m interface and implementation files, named for your entities.  But if you have it working and are happy with it, then we're done here.  :-)